# Delete cascade MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I have table `prodottipublic`:

[image: Table 1]

and I have table `roles_prodotti`:

[image: Table 2]

I want, when delete record in prodottipublic with id: 10 for example, automatically delete all records with column prodotto_id same 10 in roles_prodotti table.

this is create table codes:

```
CREATE TABLE `prodottipublic` (  `id` int(11) UNSIGNED ZEROFILL NOT NULL,  `attivo` int(1) NOT NULL,  `nome` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,  `immagine` varchar(150) DEFAULT NULL,  `immaginesx` varchar(150) DEFAULT NULL,  `descrizione` text NOT NULL,  `sololistino` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',  `listino` decimal(10,2) NOT NULL,  `sconto` int(2) DEFAULT '0',  `prezzo` decimal(10,2) DEFAULT '0.00',  `categoria_id` int(11) NOT NULL,  `meta_keywords`text,  `attributi` json NOT NULL,  `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,  `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULTCHARSET=utf8;


CREATE TABLE `roles_prodotti` (  `prodotto_id` int(11)  UNSIGNED ZEROFILL NOT NULL,  `role_id` nt(11) NOT NULL) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Comment: Is the missing bracket before `role_id` a typo?

Comment: Instead of posting an image of the table structure, post the output of [`SHOW CREATE TABLE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/show-create-table.html) as text. It is smaller but provides more information about the table.

Comment: have added create tables code

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html -  'The size and sign of integer types must be the same' - id is unsigned role_id is not , Also why does your create table not show indexes and your screen dump does?

Comment: i have edited now both id and prodotto_id have unsigned, but have the same error.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your error. Try working through the requirements in https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html and perhaps this https://www.percona.com/blog/2017/04/06/dealing-mysql-error-code-1215-cannot-add-foreign-key-constraint/

Answer (score 0):

i have solved with this:

```
ALTER TABLE `roles_prodotti` ADD CONSTRAINT ID_prodotto FOREIGN KEY (`prodotto_id`) REFERENCES `prodottipublic`(`id`)ON DELETE CASCADE
```

and before have empty roles_prodotti